# Save and load all the settings a user sets in a Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have a simple shiny app below in which the user can make some choices using those widgets. Is it possible to save and load all the settings as the user will set in the Shiny App, so that he can open the app the next time and load these same settings from a location on his computer, which then causes the app to change its settings immediately to how it used to be before?

```
#ui.r
navbarPage(
  "Application",
  tabPanel("General",
           sidebarLayout(

             sidebarPanel(
               uiOutput("tex1"),
               br(),
               uiOutput("num"),
               br(),

               uiOutput("num2")
              ),



             mainPanel(
               wellPanel(
                 h4("Format"),
                 fluidRow( # Width = sum of component columns
                   tags$style(type="text/css",
                              ".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",
                              ".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }"
                   ),
                   column(3,
                          h5("Booklet ID"),
                          div(style="display: inline-block;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;",uiOutput("num3"))


                   )
                 )
                 )



             )
           )))





#server.r
library(shiny)


server <- function(input, output,session) {

  output$tex1<-renderUI({
    textInput("text", h4("Run Name") 
    )
  })
  output$num<-renderUI({
    numericInput("nm", 
                 h4("Items"), 
                 value = 50,min = 1)
  })
  output$num2<-renderUI({
    numericInput("nm2", 
                 h4("Dimensions"), 
                 value = 1,min = 0,max = max(input$nm))
  })
  output$num3<-renderUI({
    textInput("nm3", 
              h6("Column"), 
              value = 1)
  })







}
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible with bookmarking: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/bookmarking-state.html.

`shinyApp()` has a parameter `enableBookmarking`. If you set it to `url`, you can create a link and visit the page at the state it had at the bookmark creation.

[image]

Note: You can also save the state of the app to disk, if you set the `enableBookmarking` parameter to server.

Comment: great feature and answer!

Comment: I guess that the problem with this answer is that if you close the app then the url is useless as it runs locally if you havent publish the app online.

Comment: Wouldn´t the server parameter solve this issue? See last sentence of the answer,...

Comment: It creates a folder named "shiny-bookmarks " which includes a list of my choices. But how can I call them when I restart the app and not just have them stored?